# how can I get an item and it's attachments from the current list using SP's JavaScript Client Object Model on newform.aspx?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I only recently learned/read about SharePoint's JavaScript Client Object Model. I'm reading online trying to figure this out but not having much luck.

On **newform.aspx** (and **dispform.aspx**) I want to get the current list, the last item created, and it's attachments. I now the CAML query I need to get the last item created, but first I have to get the current list and I am not sure how to do that.

I tried SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList() but that returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SP.ListOperation.Selection` properties will only have values if you're on a page where there are list items selected (a page with a list view web part)

To figure out which list you'll need to look in from the item form pages, you'll find a variable on your page at `_spPageContextInfo.pageListId` that contains the list ID. If you're uncomfortable using a global variable that starts with an underscore you can also get the page context info by calling `

```
var listId = SP.PageContextInfo.get_pageListId();
```

Then you can fetch the list by using `context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I did not know about PageContextInfo. I am going to look into what other juicy details it has hiding in it. :)